# Spring boot 2.0 onwards taking a lot of time to bind configuration properties given size of properties is approx ~7000

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

We have customized Spring cloud config as a centralized solution for enterprise as a result of which there are around 700 repos onboarded to our config server. It adds up to approx 7000 spring configuration properties and it will keep increasing. This used to work pretty fast in spring boot 1.5 but post-spring boot 2.0 Its taking a lot of time to map the configuration properties.

I am trying to upgrade it to Spring boot 2.1.8 along with spring cloud config 2.1.4 but application startup time and context refresh time has drastically increased when compared to spring boot 1.5.x.

Is there a way we can switch off relax binding or other mapping features and use it similar to spring boot 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an experience of managing such a big amount of properties, however I have some ideas that can be useful and point to the solution:

1. Why do you think its property resolution/relaxed binding rules? Maybe there are some more beans that get loaded and some of them are slow, all the can "contribute" to the slow startup time.
2. For modern machines 7000 properties is not such a big amount. So the chances are that even there was some performance degradation between spring boot 1.x and 2.x (in which I hardly believe) - it still won't be a "considerable" amount of time.
3. Since you've mentioned spring cloud config - it has a rest API that can by itself be checked for performance. If you have an actuator on the cloud config server, there is an endpoint that returns 50 last requests along with their execution times. So please check the execution times and compare between spring boot 1.5.x and 2.0.x
4. Last but not least - try to profile the application and see which beans are the real time consumers.

Comment: I tried the same application with lesser environment properties in a lower environment around ~500 approx. The application starts in less than 45 seconds, Whereas with 7000 properties its taking around 7 mins to start. Based on further debugging it seems majority of time is taken by Spring boot file : ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization, There is a new bind method introduced which binds config properties with environment "void bind(Object bean, String beanName, ConfigurationProperties annotation)". This was not the case in spring boot 1.5.

Comment: Yes but maybe the processing of properties after you get them from cloud config takes more time. I'm just saying that it should be profiled at least and its not that obvious that the binding itselft is slower

Comment: Some References of similar issue reported: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b39fdea508e5f2c904a30ab613ade785c289879d
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/16474